# Saving NULL instead of the text of HTML document in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I am making a search engine and I want to save the html document Text (Without Tags) in Mysql When the page is indexed. I am using jsoup, and the following is my code, but for some urls like wikipedia the function returns the text, but stored as NULL in Mysql , and I don't know the reason.

```
public void insertDocument(Document webPage, int URLID) throws SQLException 
{
    String query = "Update visitedpages set Document = ? where ID = ?";
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement sqlStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        String text = webPage.text();
        sqlStatement.setString (1, text);
        sqlStatement.setInt (2, URLID);
        sqlStatement.execute();
    }
    catch(SQLException s)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you print `text` before your insert it, maybe it is not the problem with your query!

Comment: FYI, you've declared this as `throws SQLException` and it doesn't need to.

Comment: What datatype is the Document column in your database?

Comment: Yes I Print it and it contains words

Comment: Also the Document field in Mysql could be NULL so, it means that it doesn't insert it.

Comment: Document data type is longtext